# The difference between OUT and OUTPUT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In an application that uses SQL Server I came across a code that uses both OUT and OUTPUT parameters.

```
 @Id   INT OUT,
 @PnNo   VARCHAR(10)  OUTPUT,
```

What is the difference between OUT and OUTPUT parameters.

Comment: They're synonyms. If a procedure has both in its definition, then either 2+ different people have contributed and not checked the syntax of the existing proc or someone is inconsistent with their own.

Comment: @DaleK I changed jobs and lost touch to the code

Comment: It's polite to reward other peoples effort by accepting their answers, assuming they were helpful and correct.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I agree with you. But it's not possible to check whether any of the answers are correct now. I changed jobs and lost touch to the code.

Comment: @Daneesha you could up-vote them, which says thank you for you effort, without saying it solves your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the 2 are synonyms. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the syntax for the clause is listed as below:

```
        [ VARYING ] [ = default ] [ OUT | OUTPUT | [READONLY] ]
```

So this denotes that either `OUT` or `OUTPUT` (or `READONLY`) can be supplied for a parameter's property. Then they are documented as follows:

> OUT | OUTPUT Indicates that the parameter is an output parameter. Use OUTPUT parameters to return values to the caller of the procedure. [The types] text, ntext, and image parameters cannot be used as OUTPUT parameters, unless the procedure is a CLR procedure. An output parameter can be a cursor placeholder, unless the procedure is a CLR procedure. A table-value data type cannot be specified as an OUTPUT parameter of a procedure.

The pipe (`|`) here means an "or", so eother `OUT` or `OUTPUT` can be used, but both are documented to do the same thing. Thus which you use is up to you, however, I personally suggest you be consistent and stick to one or the other (or at least the same one in the same object to avoid confusion).